# IE javascript redirection

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a javascript function which redirects user to a diff page. It goes like this...

```
redirect : function(url)
{
    if(!url)
        return false;

    alert(url);
    if (this.browserClass.isW3C) //IE 6.X comes here
    {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
    else if(this.browserClass.isIE4)
    {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
    else if (this.browserClass.isNN4)
    {
        window.location = url;
    }
    else
    {
        window.location = url;
    }
    return false;
},
```

But the problem is that this does not work in IE (internet explorer 6.X). After a short battle I saw that IE was redirecting when I change the code to this -

```
    if (this.browserClass.isW3C)
        setTimeout("location.href = '" +url+"'", 0);
```

Problem is solved. But what's going on here? Could someone educate me? or is it just one of those mind numbing idiosyncrasies of IE...

Comment: you're designing for IE4 and *Netscape*??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is a complete waste of time. Assignment to `location.href` works equally well in all currently extant browsers. `this.browserClass.isNN4` is a hint that this code is worrying about stuff that doesn't exist in this century. As if being stinky old browser-sniffing wasn't bad enough. (Anyway even in Netscape, both these assignments worked.)

```
setTimeout("location.href = '" +url+"'", 0);
```

Try not to pass strings to `setTimeout`, it's the same thing as `eval` with all the same problems (eg. your URL contains an apostrophe... boom). Pass a function, an inline one if necessary (`setTimeout(function() { location.href= url; }, 0);`).

However what this smells like to me is you're trapping a `click` or `mousedown` event on a link, and not cancelling the event (by returning `false` from the event handler). Consequently the link following default action can occur and may, depending on browser, override the `location.href` navigation.

Comment: The setTimeOut fix worked for me too. IE wasn't visibly updating the URL with just location.href although I think the URL might have actually changed but you couldn't bookmark it or see the new URL (weird). It was inside a jQuery click event but I was cancelling with event.preventDefault and I also tried return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concern about the Web Browser keeping history (the back and forward buttons), just use the javascript `location.replace(url)` function else you can always use the `location.href` attribute.

Source: http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-location-replace.shtml

The window.location (if I remember correctly) is an object and not a string attribute.

I don't remember if document.location is still valid in IE6 though (I quit IE6 yonkers ago).