# Automatically click the button right after page load to redirect in IE9

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript that will automatically click the button right after page load to redirect.
And, I found this perfect code:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('redirect').onclick = function(){
       haha1();
    };
   document.getElementById('redirect').click();
  }

</script>
```

However, unfortunately this code does not work in IE9
Is there any error that caused IE9 not to render or load the javascript?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why doesn't it work in IE9? What happens?

Comment: This code keeps refreshing the page infinitely... :(

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098758/ie-javascript-redirection)

Comment: @Yongju What does `haha1()` do? Also, what is the `redirect` element? Is it an anchor? If so, where does it point to?

Comment: you can try this also window.location.href = 'your_url';

Comment: Nothing wrong with the script I believe. It works in IE. add the content of haha1() to your question if you can

Comment: why do you have write again the  document.getElementById('redirect').click(); function
remove that function and try again

Comment: Hello guys! Thank your the comments. I found the solution. I set the "redirect" value in a button element and the link was echoed by Php. 
  window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('redirect').click();
  }
All I did was to change the button element to input. This fixed the problem and I removed haha() in the javascript as I found out that it does not function. Thank you all for the comments!